# SQL Server - computed date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns, create-table

I want to create 'Conferences' table and set EndDate as StartDate + ConferenceDays. Is there any way how to do that?

```
create table Conferences(
    ConferenceID int not null primary key,
    ConferenceName varchar(50) not null,
    ConferenceDays int not null,
    StartDate date not null,
    EndDate date not null,
)
```

Comment: do you want a new column which is sum of all three?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: @YashveerSingh if StartDate is 2016-01-01 and ConferenceDays is 4, I want EndDate to be 2016-01-05.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I use Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: @EuroPe you can change the formula as you want I think answer will to use computed column I added a sample column with formula you can change accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SQL server:

```
create table Conferences(
    ConferenceID int not null primary key,
    ConferenceName varchar(50) not null,
    ConferenceDays int not null,
    StartDate date not null,
    EndDate AS (dateadd(day,ConferenceDays, StartDate)) PERSISTED
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works perfectly. I tried similar with 'dateadd' but with 'Deafult' or 'Check' and here should be 'AS'. :) Thanks, one more time :)

Comment: You should explain what `persisted` means in your answer

Answer (score 0):

I suggest rethinking this a little. If EndDate is always StartDate + ConferenceDays, then you essentially have redundant data and that could be considered a violation of normalization rules.

If you're using an ORM or you've defined some class that represents the data table, then I suggest adding a property like this:

```
partial class Conference {

   DateTime EndDate { get { return this.StartDate.AddDays( this.ConferenceDays ); } }
   ... etc.
}
```

Will this work for you?

Comment: Having EndDate as a separate DB column is useful when there is a need to sort by EndDate or use it in WHERE clause.